# How to get "all but the last N fields/things" in shell script?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, cut

I often encounter the case where I need to get all the beginning of a string without some last part.

For example, the host part of a FQDN without the domain name:

```
www.example.org -> www
foo.bar.example.org -> foo.bar
foo.bar.baz.some.domain.name -> foo.bar.baz.some
```

(The same applies for other examples where you need to strip the end of the input.)

I usually use a mix of `cut` and `rev` for this, such as:

```
echo "foo.bar.example.org" | rev | cut -d "." -f 3- | rev
```

This does the trick, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you could do:

```
$ awk '{NF=NF-2}1' FS=. OFS=. file
www
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz.some
```

Generalize to the last `N` feilds where `N=2`:

```
$ awk '{NF=NF-N}1' FS=. OFS=. N=2 file
www
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz.some
```

With `sed` you could do:

```
$ sed 's/[.][^.]*[.][^.]*$//' file
www
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz.some
```

Generalized:

```
$ sed -r 's/([.][^.]*){2}$//' file
www
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz.some
```

Comment: @fedorqui I would throw `{OFS=FS}` into the `BEGIN` block to avoid that assignment on every line in the input and `NR=(NF-2)` as the condition for empty block won't print an empty line when `NF=2` which may or may not be useful for a given usecase.